# Can I write prepared statements in procedural style?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

The example from the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) is using OOP. Is there a way to do it procedurally?

Comment: Why in Gods name do you want to write it procedurally? Speed microoptimisations? I'd prefer readability, conciseness and maintainability over a little speed difference in almost any case.

Comment: Some people have their reasons. Maybe they are familiar with the standard `mysql_query` syntax and don't want to instantiate the PDO object.

Comment: @Sune. I been doing mysql all through procedural so far and just wanted to see if there was a way to use prepared statements without having to do it with objects. Just more familiar with it

Comment: and @Byron: Well, that *is* a reason ;) and a fine one for me, I was really more just being curious; sorry if it seemed as if I was trying to be rude.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MySQLi has procedural-style function calls that can handle prepared statements. (Some of the procedural-style functions are deprecated, however.)

http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

Comment: Yes they did depreciate some of them.  But added new statements in their place.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

Comment: *Deprecate, to depreciate is to decrease in value over time :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. As far as I know PDO is completely object-oriented, but you may want to look into [mysqli](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) which allows both procedural and OO styles.

> Procedural coders will find the basics
>   almost identical. Where before you
>   would used a function such as
>   mysql_connect(), the new function is
>   simply mysqli_connect(). Most of the
>   old mysql_x functions have equivalent
>   mysqli_x versions.

[Source](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/php/article.php/3599166/Connecting-and-prepared-statements-with-the-mysqli-extension.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Procedural style syntax is a little more verbose and less preferred among most modern PHP developers.  On top of that, PDO offers more sophisticated methods versus mysqli.

Regardless, yes, you can execute prepared statements with mysqli using procedural syntax.

Code: ([PHPize.online Demo](https://phpize.online/s/cC))

```
$price = '80.00';
$id = 3;

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE full_price = ?
  AND product_id = ?
SQL;

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $price, $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

foreach (mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt) as $row) {
     var_dump($row);
}
```